# SubSet of a object

Tags: java, oop, jpa

I have a class Doctor and a class Hospital. A doctor can work in different hospital.
I have a class Person. A person can have many doctor.

In my Docteur Class

```
public class Doctor{
  public Long Id
  ...

  @OneToMany
  private List<Hospital> hospital;

}
```

Example Doctor Borduas, work in Hospital: A, B, C.

Bob is sick, and see the doctor Borduas, but it see it only in Hopital A and C.

It's like A person have only a subset of value of Hospital.

How to represent this in JPA

Comment: you mean how to represent this in a Java model, since JPA simply takes your O-O model and allows it to be persistable ...

Comment: ya, but you don't necessary get the structure you was thinking with jpa

Comment: in which case present us with the "structure you was thinking" and then people have basis for comment

Comment: I don't know, i can't have a person with only a list of Doctor. Would need a kind of Object PersonDoctorHospital.

Comment: a person doesn't have a Doctor. They may have a "preferred" (or nominal) doctor but they get appointments (or Consultations) with any one of a number of Doctors. Also an appointment doesn't have to be at a Hospital ... could be at a medical centre / doctors surgery (which in many countries is not a hospital)

Comment: If I have cancer, a specialist Doctor X will follow me and so on. Maybe this doctor  work in Paris, Montreal, New York and Chicago.

In this case, will probably be interested see it only in New York, Chicago (if i live near them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a "Consultation" entity:

- Consultation - ManyToOne - Person
- Consultation - ManyToOne - Doctor
- Consultation - ManyToOne - Hospital

(of course, each of these associations can be in the other direction)

A consultation represents a person visiting a doctor in a hospital.

It's up to the application to only allow the creation of a consultation if the doctor of the consultation has the hospital of the consultation in his set of hospitals.